Opaque C structs with wrapper struct
I was reading up about opaque structs in c and I was wondering why seemingly (at least I didn't find anything) nobody does something like this
struct LED_ {
    short pin;
    bool on;
};

typedef struct LED {
    uint8_t _raw_data_[sizeof(struct LED_)];
} LED;

and only expose LED. This way I can still put it on the stack and the only additional information that leaks is the struct size.
LED l = DEFAULT_LED;

I would have to cast it every time internally but that shouldn't be a problem? Is this a bad Idea? Why?

Alignment is one issue - and how would you expose LED (defined using the size of LED_) without exposing LED_?

I’m voting to close this question because OP could find answer without posting this Q

Some counter arguments: code readability, extra level of castings, limited functionality, no added value, ...

IF this were done, 1) incorrect syntax to initialise the struct LED, and 2) integer value of DEFAULT_LED would be pushed into a uint8_t but accessed (presumably) as a short. Big Endian vs Little Endian... Advice to beginner: If the experienced people aren't trying to do something, it's probably for a good reason.

@FrontendC, "and only expose LED" --> Posted code cannot do that.  With typedef struct LED { uint8_t _raw_data_[sizeof(struct LED_)]; } LED;, code also needs struct LED_ { short pin; bool on; };.  So one cannot do LED l = DEFAULT_LED; with out defining LED and LED_.  One could do struct LED *pointer; without exposing LED_.

Alignment and aliasing aside, this also does expose the internals of struct LED_, which defeats the purpose. Also, it is usually a good thing that the caller can't declare objects of the opaque type. Just design your interface using pointers and have them declare pointers only.

@DanielWalker yea sorry, that makes total sense. I've just decided not to look at SO for a month after reading the first comments that where just toxic. Thanks you two for providing actually useful information.

There are two main problems with this: alignment and strict aliasing.
The wrapper struct contains a single array of type uint8_t, so the alignment of this struct is 1.  The "real" struct contains a member of type short, so it has an alignment of at least 2.  Because of this, an instance of struct LED_  placed on the stack may not be properly aligned for the short member of type struct LED_.
Also, taking the address of a struct LED, casting it to a pointer to struct LED_ and dereferencing is a strict aliasing violation.  The cases in which aliasing is allowed is specified in section 6.5p7 of the C standard:

An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
expression that has one of the following types:

a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
subaggregate or contained union), or
a character type.


And such a case does not fall under any of the above allowed cases.

There are two reasons that I can think of.

Some processors have alignment requirements and there's no guarantee that LED would have the same alignment as struct LED_.  Therefore, if you tried to do something like
short
get_pin(const LED *led)
{
    return ((struct LED_*)led)->pin;
}

you could invoke undefined behavior.
Now, you could fix this by using alignas which has been available since C11.

This is the more important issue.  The purpose of an opaque structure type is that the structure's actual layout should not be visible to the user.  In order for sizeof(struct LED_) to be meaningful, the compilation unit would need to see the definition of struct LED_.


The way opaque structures are typically presented is by putting
typedef struct LED_ LED; // There is something called `struct LED_` and we'll abbreviate it as `LED`.

in a header file and the actual definition:
struct LED_ {
    short pin;
    bool on;
};

in a source file.

"Now, you could fix this by using alignas which has been available since C11." It would still be a strict aliasing issue even if alignment is assured.
